# Bootstrap V5.3 doesn't effect on my additional file

Tags: bootstrap-5

I using bootstrap 5 in my project but when i include my another css file that are not effect on my project like background colour or some. Other properties and i also tried ! important sign in css but it was not effect.

Anyone have this problem solution.